# Controlling ListView Row data

Tags: android, listview

I'm implementing a shopping cart system with ListView. A plus and a minus button on each row manage the number of item displayed on the textview. They would also send an event to the real cart to update the number. However, I found out that the temporary data holder changed every time the app was scrolled, which make the `viewholder` class and the real cart behave incorrectly. So how can I correctly store the value of each row to send to the other class?

Below is my `getView` method

```
 public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View vi = view;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_item_list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder(vi);
        vi.setTag( holder );

    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    if(data.size()>0)
    {
        final TextView finalQuantityView = holder.quantityView;
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = ( ModelItem ) data.get(i);


        holder.titleView.setText(tempValues.getName());
        holder.priceView.setText(tempValues.getPrice());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(tempValues.getPicture());
        holder.unitView.setText(tempValues.getUnit());
        if (tempValues.isHaveQuantity())
            finalQuantityView.setText(tempValues.getQuantity().getQuantity());
        else {
            finalQuantityView.setText("0");
            tempValues.setQuantity(new ModelQuantity(0));
        }
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.list_item_plus:
                    {
                        tempValues.getQuantity().increaseQuantity();
                        finalQuantityView.setText(String.valueOf(tempValues.getQuantity().getQuantity()));
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(new CartController(tempValues.getItemOrderNumber(), true, tempValues.getQuantity()));
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.list_item_minus: {
                        tempValues.getQuantity().decreaseQuantity();
                        finalQuantityView.setText(String.valueOf(tempValues.getQuantity().getQuantity()));
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(new CartController(tempValues.getItemOrderNumber(), false, tempValues.getQuantity()));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        };
        holder.minusButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
        holder.plusButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }
```

I do know that something is not right with the OnClickListener, but I do not know what I have to do to make it right.